# Ruby: Most concise way to use an ENV variable if it exists, otherwise use default value

Tags: ruby, hash

In Ruby, I am trying to write a line that uses a variable if it has been set, otherwise default to some value:

```
myvar = # assign it to ENV['MY_VAR'], otherwise assign it to 'foobar'
```

I could write this code like this:

```
if ENV['MY_VAR'].is_set? #whatever the function is to check if has been set
  myvar = ENV['MY_VAR']
else
  myvar = 'foobar'
end
```

But this is rather verbose, and I'm trying to write it in the most concise way possible. How can I do this?

Comment: For non-ENV variables, which don't fail nicely when not set, you'll need to use something like `defined?( some_variable ) ? some_variable : "default value"`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
myvar = ENV['MY_VAR'] || 'foobar'
```

N.B. This is slightly incorrect (if the hash can contain the value `nil`) but since `ENV` contains just strings it is probably good enough.

Comment: **How does this handle empty strings, `""`?** For example if I set my ENV variable with `MY_VAR= rails s`, would `myvar` get set to `""` or would it get set to `"foobar"`?

Comment: **Answer:** It will get set to an empty string, `""`. Depending on what you're going for, that could be the desired result. If not, you can also use `ENV.key?( "MY_VAR" )` to see if the variable is set at all?

Answer (score 48):

The most reliable way for a general Hash is to ask if it has the key:

```
myvar = h.has_key?('MY_VAR') ? h['MY_VAR'] : 'default'
```

If you don't care about `nil` or `false` values (i.e. you want to treat them the same as "not there"), then undur_gongor's approach is good (this should also be fine when `h` is `ENV`):

```
myvar = h['MY_VAR'] || 'foobar'
```

And if you want to allow `nil` to be in your Hash but pretend it isn't there (i.e. a `nil` value is the same as "not there") while allowing a `false` in your Hash:

```
myvar = h['MY_VAR'].nil? ? 'foobar' : h['MY_VAR']
```

In the end it really depends on your precise intent and you should choose the approach that matches your intent. The choice between `if/else/end` and `? :` is, of course, a matter of taste and "concise" doesn't mean "least number of characters" so feel free to use a ternary or `if` block as desired.

Comment: Dittos @undur_gongor.  Thanks for being thorough!

Comment: For the `h` in the code above - is that just a temporary value for `hash` or should we be relating `h` with something from our code/names?

Comment: @CanuckT `h` is a generic hash, could be any hash at all. I think I used `h` rather than `ENV` because there's nothing specific to `ENV` or how it behaves, it is just about hashes.

Answer (score 31):

```
hash.fetch(key) { default_value }
```

Will return the value if it exists, and return `default_value` if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Or `hash.fetch(key, default_value)` if the default doesn't depend on the key.

Comment: @mu is too short: Yes. Usually I'm doing `hash.fetch(key) { raise "#{key.inspect} doesn't exist!" }`, so I wasn't 100% sure of the correct order when there's two parameters.

Comment: I (like almost everyone else it seems) tend to forget that `fetch` even exists so +1 for using the whole API.

Comment: @muistooshort: Why don't most people use it? Is it because it's too long, or because the tutorials don't teach it?

Comment: Probably the same reason no one uses `Array#at`: they don't know about it, tutorials don't cover it, they think "concise" means "short", they think a mess of symbols is more Rubyish than a method call, etc. Programmers are as much victims of group-think and habit as anyone else despite the individualistic streak that a lot of programmers like to think they have. But now we're wondering into http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ territory and risking heresy.

Comment: @muistooshort: Why would you use `at`? Because it's more English-like, or because it accepts fewer types of arguments?

Comment: I can't think of a non-artificial reason right now. I do prefer `a.push(x)` over `a << x` though (possibly due to bad experiences with people over-doing operator overloading C++).

Answer (score 14):

This works best for me:

```
ENV.fetch('VAR_NAME',"5445")
```

Comment: Strange! how is that? could you please edit your answer to tell us some details about it?

Comment: I've found more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985660/rails-difference-between-env-fetch-and-env - Cheers

Answer (score 6):

```
myvar = ENV.fetch('MY_VAR') { 'foobar' }
```

`'foobar'` being the default if  `ENV['MY_VAR']` is unset.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not relevant in the specific example you gave since you're really asking about hash keys, not variables, Ruby does give a way to check variable definition. Use the `defined?` keyword (it's not a method, but a keyword since it needs special handling by the interpreter), like so:

```
a = 1
defined? a
  #=> "local-variable"

@a = 2
defined? @a
  #=> "instance-variable"

@@a = 3
defined? @@a
  #=> "class-variable"

defined? blahblahblah
  #=> nil
```

Hence you could do:

```
var = defined?(var) ? var : "default value here"
```

As far as I know, that's the only way other than an ugly `begin`/`rescue`/`end` block to define a variable in the way that you ask without risking a NameError. As I said, this doesn't apply to hashes since:

```
hash = {?a => 2, ?b => 3}
defined? hash[?c]
  #=> "method"
```

i.e. you're checking that the method `[]` is defined rather than the key/value pair you're using it to access.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible alternative, which will work even if ENV['MY_VAR'] turnsout to be a false value

```
myvar  = ENV['MY_VAR'].presence || 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Demand](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-demand) gem which I wrote allows this to be extremely concise and DRY:

```
myvar = demand(ENV['MY_VAR'], 'foobar')
```

This will use `ENV['MY_VAR']` only if it is present. That is, it will discard it just if it's nil, empty or a whitespace-only string, giving the default instead.

If a valid value for `ENV['MY_VAR']` is falsy (such as `false`), or an invalid value is truthy (such as `""`), then solutions like using `||` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am new guy to Ruby, post the answer I found at 2021, maybe useful for someone.

check if env key exists:

```
 include?(name) → true or false
 has_key?(name) → true or false
 member?(name) → true or false
 key?(name) → true or false
```

get env with default value:

```
 ENV.fetch(name, :default_val)
```

ref: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/ENV.html

Answer (score -2):

`myvar = ENV['MY_VAR'].is_set? ? ENV['MY_VAR'] : 'foobar'`

This way you keep the .is_set? method.

Comment: Is `is_set?` a ruby method? I thought I made that up because I didn't know the name of the method I was asking for.

Comment: At least in my version of ruby there is no is_set?, there is a ENV.has_key?