# Rails: difference between ENV.fetch() and ENV[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

What is the difference between these two syntax:

`ENV.fetch("MY_VAR")`

`ENV['MY_VAR']`

I've seen Rails 5 use both versions of these in difference places and can't figure out what the difference is (apart from the first one being more characters to type).

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is pretty clear to everyone else what they're asking, not everyone consults a dictionary when asking a question. You're welcome to provide your own answer if you need to display your command of the English language.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The `ENV` hash-like object is plain Ruby, not part of Rails. From the [fine `ENV#[]` manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html#method-c-5B-5D):

> Retrieves the value for environment variable `name` as a String. Returns `nil` if the named variable does not exist.

and the [fine `ENV#fetch` manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html#method-c-fetch):

> Retrieves the environment variable `name`.
>
> If the given name does not exist and neither `default` nor a block a provided an IndexError is raised. If a block is given it is called with the missing name to provide a value. If a default value is given it will be returned when no block is given.

So just like [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), the only difference is that `fetch` allows you to specify the behavior if a key is not found (use a default value passed to `fetch`, default block passed to `fetch`, or raise an exception) whereas `[]` just silently gives you `nil` if the key isn't found.

In the specific case of:

```
ENV.fetch("MY_VAR")
ENV['MY_VAR']
```

the difference is that `ENV['MY_VAR']` will give you `nil` if there is no `MY_VAR` environment variable but `ENV.fetch('MY_VAR')` will raise an exception.

Comment: This is how the default value is used: `ENV.fetch('NON_EXISTENT') {'returns this string'}`

Comment: or `ENV.fetch('NON_EXISTENT', 'my default value')` @estani

Comment: @YannickSchuchmann indeed! My example should have been `ENV.fetch('NON_EXISTENT') { <compute the value> }` or something more appropriate for a block. Otherwise the second parameter in you comment is much better.